# Multi rows concatenation using CTE in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Input:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Product') is not null drop table #Product
if object_id('tempdb..#ProductFeatures') is not null drop table #ProductFeatures
create table #Product(Product_id int, Product_label nvarchar(200))
create table #ProductFeatures(Product_id int, FeatureId int, Feature_label nvarchar(30), Feature_Value nvarchar(30))

insert into #Product(Product_id, Product_label) values
 (1, 'HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 42')
,(2, 'Road-650 Black, 58')

insert into #ProductFeatures(Product_id, FeatureId, Feature_label, Feature_Value) values
 (1, 1, 'Color', 'Silver')
,(1, 2, 'Height', '42')
,(1, 3, 'Widht',  '12')

,(2, 1, 'Color', 'Black')
,(2, 2, 'Height', '58')
,(2, 3, 'Widht', '58')
```

The desired output :
Concatenate each features rows group and update the product label
Condition : add feature label if this last doesn't exists in the product label.

For example : 'Silver' will not be added because it exists in the product label.

```
Product_id  Product_label
----------- ------------------------------------
1           HL Mountain Frame - Silver, 42 12
2           Road-650 Black, 58
```

Question :
How to figure it out CTE (and not using cursor) ?

Comment: Sql Server Cursor
But i thinks that there more simpler solution

Answer (score 1):

For example you can do this with `FOR XML`

```
UPDATE P
 SET P.Product_label = P2.newValue
FROM #Product AS P
INNER JOIN (
SELECT IP.Product_ID, IP.Product_label +
ISNULL(

        (SELECT ' ' + PF.Feature_value AS [text()]
        FROM #ProductFeatures AS PF
        WHERE PF.Product_id = IP.Product_id
        AND IP.Product_label NOT LIKE '%' + PF.Feature_value + '%'
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), '') AS newValue
FROM #Product AS IP
) AS P2
ON P.Product_ID = P2.Product_ID
```

Comment: Yeah, it's true, but OP wants to update Product_Label ;)

Answer (score 1):

Darka's solution is very good. I'd like to provide an alternative way, using pivot:

```
----uncomment below query to see how it works ;)
--SELECT Product_id, Product_label, REPLACE(Product_label, CONCAT([Color],', ', [Height]), CONCAT([Color],', ' ,[Height],' ', [Widht])) AS NewLabel
--FROM (
--  SELECT Product_id, Product_label, [Color], [Height], [Widht]
--  FROM (
--      SELECT PF.Product_id, P.Product_label , PF.Feature_label , PF.Feature_Value 
--      FROM #ProductFeatures AS PF INNER JOIN #Product P ON PF.Product_id = P.Product_id 
--  ) AS dt
--  PIVOT (MAX(Feature_Value) FOR Feature_label IN ([Color], [Height], [Widht])) AS pvt
--) AS T


UPDATE t1 SET Product_label = REPLACE(t2.Product_label, CONCAT(t2.[Color],', ', t2.[Height]), CONCAT(t2.[Color],', ' ,t2.[Height],' ', t2.[Widht]))
FROM #Product AS t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Product_id, Product_label, [Color], [Height], [Widht]
    FROM (
        SELECT PF.Product_id, P.Product_label , PF.Feature_label , PF.Feature_Value 
        FROM #ProductFeatures AS PF INNER JOIN #Product P ON PF.Product_id = P.Product_id 
    ) AS dt
    PIVOT (MAX(Feature_Value) FOR Feature_label IN ([Color], [Height], [Widht])) AS pvt
) AS t2 ON t1.Product_id = t2.Product_id 

SELECT *
FROM #Product
```

Note: above solution is not optimized... But i mentioned that is alternative way.

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: Using pivot would be great,
But the set of features is not the same for each product, and we can't list them for dynamic query pivot.

Answer (score 0):

To @Darka,
thanks for your help

Just little adjustment in script, because we search for the hole word :)

```
charindex(' ' + PF.Feature_value, IP.Product_label) = 0

SELECT IP.Product_ID, IP.Product_label +
ISNULL(

        (SELECT ' ' + PF.Feature_value AS [text()]
        FROM #ProductFeatures AS PF
        WHERE PF.Product_id = IP.Product_id
        AND charindex(' ' + PF.Feature_value, IP.Product_label) = 0
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), '') AS newValue
FROM #Product AS IP
```